# Apollo GraphQL iOS

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollo-ios

I add this run script on my swift3 project

```
APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH="$(eval find $FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS -name "Apollo.framework" -maxdepth 1)"

if [ -z "$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH" ]; then
echo "error: Couldn't find Apollo.framework in FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS; make sure to add the framework to your project."
exit 1

cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}"
$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh generate '/*.graphql' --schema schema.json --output API.swift
```

When I build I get this error:

```
find: /Users/userName/Documents/Swift: No such file or directory
find: Apps/appName/appName: No such file or directory
find: /Users/userName/Documents/Swift: No such file or directory
find: Apps/appName/Carthage/Build/iOS: No such file or directory
++ exec apollo-codegen generate '/*.graphql' --schema schema.json --output API.swift
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

Answer (score 0):

with the following versions

```
- Apollo (0.8.0):
    - Apollo/Core (= 0.8.0)
- Apollo/Core (0.8.0)
```

I had to change

`$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh`

to:

`$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/Resources/check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh`